# How to send raw signed transaction with Solnet .net?

Tags: signing

I use following .net core library to send signed transaction https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet

I send the encoded raw transaction from react app with web3.js, and accept the string on server side, then do this:

```
var rpcClient = ClientFactory.GetClient(_solanaConfiguration.RpcUrl);
        
        var tx = Encoders.Base58.DecodeData(encodedRawTransaction);

        var firstSig = rpcClient.SendTransaction(tx);
```

But I get following response:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32002,"message":"Transaction simulation failed: Blockhash not found","data":{"accounts":null,"err":"BlockhashNotFound","logs":[],"unitsConsumed":0}},"id":0}
```

I tried with node, which works, so I am signing tx correctly.

Comment: Are you on the right network? I got this error a few times when I created the blockhash on devnet, but tried to send to mainnet.

Answer (score 3):

Found the way, just encode base64 on client side instead base58, and use `var firstSig = rpcClient.SendTransaction(tx);` and tx as string base64.